# Answers finished by "thanks"

Tags: discussion, culture

I'm seeing a strange habit on the rise for the past few weeks: Answer posts that are finished by "*Thanks, NameOfAnswerPoster*". Of course I delete that if there are other things to fix in the post.

My only question is if anyone can think of a reason why more and more users finish their answers with "thanks"? It strikes me as odd to thank someone for a deed you did. Do more people with a language background that does not differ between "you're welcome" and "thank you" flock SO (is there even such a language?), or can someone think of another reason?

Comment: I think it means `thanks for the (potential) rep`, possibly on a subconscious level.

Comment: Sometimes I end my questions with "You're welcome" just to throw people off

Comment: I find it even more annoying that some people go to the length and remove the thanks as the only edit. Pollutes my reviewing - Being polite never hurt anyone.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Think of it like the closing of a letter - a closing salutation followed by their name, as in:

> Dear Mr. Jones,
>
> In response to your request, we have forty schwargels available for delivery.
>
> Thanks,
>
> John Doe

"Thanks" in this context is just an empty word, like "Sincerely" or "Regards" or "Yours". Many people used to writing letters and e-mails will do this, especially those trained in formal English.

Comment: In English classes I was never taught that you can finish a letter with "Thanks". I accepted your answer as I liked the reasoning the best. ;-)

Comment: Well it is more informal than most closings so that's probably why. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe they mean "thank you for reading me." I am not sure it is something a native speaker of English would say, but not all users speak English as first language (including me).

The reason of writing that is probably the same for which users write *thank you in advance* in their questions.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of contributors aren't native speakers, which might explain this. It could be that they intend to end their answer with something like "regards, nameofanswerer".